# If $\phi$ is injective linear map $\mathbb{R}^r \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^s$ then $\operatorname{Im} \phi$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^s$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

My optimization theory handbook says that

If $\phi$ is injective linear map $\mathbb{R}^r \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^s$ then $\operatorname{Im} \phi$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^s$, where $\operatorname{Im}\phi$ denotes image of map $\phi$.

I don't see how it is true? Can anyone explain? Author takes this statement as granted, without any proof.

Comment: $s$ is a finite number? In a finite dimensional real vector space, any subspace is closed.

Comment: yes, its finite. really?

Comment: @luka5z Yes, it's the product of locally compact spaces, so that the image of a compact set in the domain is compact in the image, hence the image is locally compact, hence complete, hence closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of a linear map with finite dimensional source is a (finite dimensional) linear subspace, which is always closed, in particular in $\mathbb{R}^s$. I don't see why you need the map to be injective. To see it's closed (taking for granted it is a linear subspace) consider a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ and a sequence made up of linear combinations of these. This converges iff the components converge and the limit is trivially again in the same subspace.

Comment: may I ask why this fails in infinite dimensional subspaces?

Comment: (proper) infinite dimensional subspaces $Y$ of some (topological) vector space $X$ can be dense, so their closure is all of $X$. (Typical example is the space of infinitely often differentiable fucntions as subspace of the continuous one with then topology of uniform convergence).

Comment: or polynomials in continuous functions space?

Comment: Yes, the polynomial functions (on $[0,1]$, say) form a dense subspace of $C^0([0,1])$ when equipped with the $\sup$ -Norm. That's a consequence of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 2):

If $V \subset \mathbb R^s$ is any subspace, consider the canonical map $\mathbb R^s \to \mathbb R^s/V$ with kernel $V$. A linear map between finite dimensional spaces is continuous, hence the kernel is closed as the pre-image of the closed subset $\{0\}$.

Comment: This argument seems circular: how do you show a linear map between finite-dimensional real vector spaces is continuous without already knowing the kernel is closed? Moreover, the quotient topology on $\mathbf R^s/V$ (presumably the is the intended topology, which was not mentioned) is Hausdorff if and only if $V$ is closed in $\mathbf R^s$, so here too I suspect you would already want to know $V$ is closed first so you know the quotient space is nice topologically.